# RoR Rake 10.4.2 Error: "Don't know how to build task 'db:'"

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I want to create a MySQL database in Ruby on Rails using:

```
rake db: create
```

But it gives me out an error:

> rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'db:'

I am running Ubuntu and cant find answers on the internet about my version of rake (10.4.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `rake db:create` without a blank between `db:` and `create`.

If you type `rake -T` you can find the available rake tasks with their proper names.

Comment: `rake db:create` (without the blank) didn't work? What do you get when executing `rake -T`?

Comment: Seriously, thanks a lot, the problem was, when I tried to solve it before, Ive added gem rake to gemfile, so it gave out an error. But I deleted it and ran the command as you've said, and it works! Thanks a lot!